# express-formidable access to events

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

So being novice in Express and Node, I fear I must be not understanding something fundamental about middleware. I am trying to upload a file using express-formidable, and I've got it to work (as far as taking the file and uploading it to the directory of my choice). However, I would love a progress bar or to be able to do something at the start of the upload such as choose the file name. I see a lot of examples of regular formidable using the 'progress' or 'file' event. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to access this with express-formidable. Since I can't create an IncomingForm, I don't know where the events are or how to bind them.

What am I missing about how express-formidable works? Does it cut out everything about formidable and just stuff a file where you tell it? Or do you have access to everything formidable?

Here's an example of a route I have called ingest, which is where I receive an uploaded file and process it.

```
app.post('/ingest', function(req, res) {
    /*I want to be able to show progress here, and do other things
    like set the file name before it's saved, but by the time I get here
    the file is already processed and saved, and I can't figure out how
    to access events using '.on' if there's no form object*/
});
```

Comment: Can you show anything?

Comment: There's not really much to show.. express-formidable saves the file upload before I get a chance to do anything, so the POST request I have going to my /ingest route doesn't have a chance to do anything. I gave a shot in the dark thinking maybe the events got moved to the file object but that was useless: app.post('/ingest', function(req, res) {
    req.files.on('progress', function() {
        console.log("some progress");
    });
});  I don't know where .parse or .on live now